# How to add wrapper (like div) to a tag using Pseudo-element :after using css and give border to it?

Tags: css

Can i give **perfect** `border-radius` to images using `:after` , `:before` and `content:""`? I know I can wrap images in `span` or `div` to do it. but I'm just curious if i can without adding extra element to html

I need to add perfect border to images but I [cannot add border to `<img>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8444645/how-to-get-perfect-border-radius-on-images-in-all-browsers) because it's doesn't come perfect in all browser.

see my old question to know the problem [How to get perfect border radius on images in all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8444645/how-to-get-perfect-border-radius-on-images-in-all-browsers)

```
<div class="small-images">
<img src="theme/a/img/Image_232_black.jpg">
<img src="theme/a/img/product1-232-bottom.jpg">
<img src="theme/a/img/product1-232-up.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: define "perfect", what problems have you had with other browsers?

Comment: @amosrivera - Sorry i linked to wrong page

Comment: Have a look at [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v6FH8/). Is that what you want to do?

Comment: @Jam ... no, he wants to round the image corners too.

Comment: @Jitendra - Do you know that IE6, IE7, IE8 won't handle it?

Comment: @roXon Thanks for clarifying. [This](http://jsfiddle.net/v6FH8/1/) perhaps?

Comment: @Jam ... noupe. Not good. Take a look in Chrome / Webkit. Chrome is a bit dummy.

Comment: @JamWaffles - see my this question to understand the problem of giving border to image directly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8444645/how-to-get-perfect-border-radius-on-images-in-all-browsers

Comment: @roXon Alright, I'll stop making a fool of myself ;-) The day when things 'just work' with browsers will be a strange but welcome one.

Comment: @Jitendra - Give it as a background-image to a div and give the div a border-radius style. That's the easiest way i guess.

Comment: @techfoobar - I know that way. and I need to give border to each image inside div. I want to do it without adding extra element to html if possible

Comment: @Jam :D glad someone has a sane sense of humor this days. I think this is most important than giving wrong/correct answers/tries.

Comment: @Jam - The day the word 'Crossbrowser' will become actually an uncommon word ... We'll be all drinking in a pub!

Comment: @Jitendra... please... may I write a small jQuery snippet that will help you? Is that fine for you?

Comment: @roXon Thank you. I'd rather fail miserably and enjoy it than fail even harder and not. You can have a beer, I don't like it, although I can't see us ever not having to hack CSS for different browsers.

Comment: @Jam :D ... Sad but true friend. I remember it like yesterday, when I've wrote my first website (If I can call it so :D ) and a friend's voice telling me: *'... well, nice. Have you tested it in different browsers than IE ?'* :D Browsers should finally split engines from the W3C standards, and I can't wait the day there will be a central database that will be connected by any existent browser to update the database.

Comment: @roXon - you mean to wrap `<div>` to each `<img>` using jquery?

Comment: @roXon You should have seen _my_ first website! Safari turned it into vomit and IE just borked. It's nice to look back and see how far I've come. It would be great if there was a single, good rendering engine made by W3C; so much time could be saved.

Comment: @Jam It's a good suggestion we could ticket.

Comment: @Jitendra Look at my answer. Actually we removed the images and just stole each image `src` and give it to the replacing element background.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS container pseudo element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11586192/css-container-pseudo-element)

Answer (score 1):

Just a trick is to do it with a little bit of jQuery:

**[DEMO jsBin](http://jsbin.com/asidof/edit#javascript,html,live)**

(Look in mozilla, chrome, ie9, opera)

The jquery:

```
$('.small-images img').bind('load each',function(){
  var img = $(this);
  var imgH = img.height();
  var imgW = img.width();
  var src = img.attr('src');
  img.after('<div class="rounded">');
  img.next('.rounded').css({
    backgroundImage: 'url('+src+')',
    width: imgW+'px',
    height: imgH+'px'
  }).end().remove();
});
```

The needed CSS:

```
  .rounded{
    border-radius:20px;
    border:4px solid #444;
  }
```

And your HTML:

```
<div class="small-images">
   <img src="theme/a/img/Image_232_black.jpg">
   <img src="theme/a/img/product1-232-bottom.jpg">
   <img src="theme/a/img/product1-232-up.jpg">
</div>
```

As you can see it replaces images with a DIV that has a background-image grabbed by the image `src` itself.

Comment: +1 Thanks for nice try but then I cannot use `alt` attribute for images.

Comment: I mean screen reader and search engine will not have access to images in background

Comment: @Jitendra They will. We can just set (instead of hiding them) inside the jQuery height and width '0px'. So the images will be 'on page' as your 'alt' attributes. What do you think? (another solution can be to add a position absolute and margin-left:-9000px, to just distance them from the viewport. A common trick. Or even just make them `opacity:0;`)