# How to keep border inside to take ribbon over to div?

Tags: css

In this example http://jsfiddle.net/aNmvc/15/ the red ribbon should touch the the edges of `div` which has border. How to achieve that?
Is there a way to get border inside or something else?

HTML

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="corner">
  <span href="#">Best Ribbon around</span>  
   </div>
   <img src="http://lorempixel.com/250/300/sports/1/">
</div>
```

CSS

```
.box {border:2px solid green; position:relative;padding:3%; width:260px; background:#ccc; overflow:hidden;}

.corner {
    background-color: #a00;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    left: -3em;
    top: 2.5em;
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);

}
.corner span {
    border: 1px solid #faa;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    font-size:.8em;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding: 0.5em 4em;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you accept @inderanil answers but you can do this with `box-shadow` property like this:

```
.box {
    position:relative;
    padding:3%;
    width:260px;
    background:#ccc;
    overflow:hidden;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px green inset;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px green inset;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px green inset;
}
```

### http://jsfiddle.net/aNmvc/18/

Answer (score 1):

Try this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/aNmvc/16/

Basically, move the border and the background and padding to the image, and that way, the `div.box` can display till the edge and hide the rest.

Comment: @Indranil - But in my actual implementation I'm using round corner. which is not perfect of Images http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8444645/how-to-get-perfect-border-radius-on-images-in-all-browsers so I can't add border to images. Only to give perfect round corners to box i added an extra `div`

Comment: @JitendraVyas so what you can do is have 2 divs in there. One #box, one inside the #box, say the .imagecontainer, and then the image.

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the border, padding, and background color from the `box` class and add it to the image inside:

```
.box { position:relative; overflow:hidden;}
.box img { 
    border:2px solid green;
    padding: 10px;
    background:#ccc;
}
```