# Can I use border-radious on image CSS?

Tags: css

Can I use `display:block;` and `border-radius` on an image in CSS? Is this contrary to CSS principles?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get perfect border radius on images in all browsers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8444645/how-to-get-perfect-border-radius-on-images-in-all-browsers)

Comment: If you spell it `border-radius`, sure ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes you can. :)**

You can easily give the image a `border-radius` of whatever number you like.

 50% or more would be and round image. You can also use `px`.

---

For example:

You have an image somewhere in your html document:

```
<img id="image" src="Your source">
```

In your css file you can simply write:

```
#image {
    border-radius: 50px; <-- example number
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8445099/1405376) by yusuf:

```
.img-border{
    border-radius:15px;
    -moz-border-radius:15px;
    -webkit-border-radius:15px;
    border:3px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, img tags are inline-block elements, but you can change its width and height like block elements.

Like this for example:

```
    .img-circular{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-image: url('http://strawberry-fest.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/Coca-Cola-logo.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 100px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
    -moz-border-radius: 100px;
    }
```